# Is this circuit safe to be powered via USB for my 3 V 350 mA LEDs?

Tags: voltage, led, usb

I'm building a simple circuit connected via USB to a number of LEDs in parallel, but I've always heard that USB connections are 5 V so I put a 10 Ohm resistor in series with the LEDs as shown on the example.

[image]

The LEDs seemed dimmer than originally advertised so I tested one of them without the resistor to see what would happen, and it was way brighter and did not burn out. So I checked with the multimeter and, when going through the LED, it would register 3.0 - 3.2 V. When going through the resistor setup, about 2.8 V. **But** if I check the voltage of the USB connection with a multimeter it shows 5V...

The USB connection comes from a port on my monitor which is connected to my PC.

Would it be safe to run the LEDs via the USB connection, as in, it will always give me 3 - 3.2 V?

Comment: First, you didn't include your set up. Second, you're measuring wrong if the voltage across the LED is different than the USB in the "no resistor" case. How long and thin are your wires? That voltage has to be dropped somewhere!

Comment: Pedro, how many LEDs in parallel and what type of LED did you use? (Datasheet is needed.) Likely, you over-topped the current compliance of the USB port. Since the behavior of USB ports in such cases is implementation-dependent, but as one of several options is to lower the output voltage, that's probably the type of port you have and it lowered the output voltage to what you measured so as to keep the current within its compliance.

Comment: Totally forgot the measurements! Sorry! @MOSFET 18AWG wires, not longer than 3M (for now), [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1636581.pdf), and i'll update the question with the setup!

Comment: You put 6 LEDs that take 350mA each to an USB port? Totaling 2.1A?

Comment: @Justme even tho they say that they take 350mA on the datasheet, on my multimeter it reports 150mA@3V totalling the expected 0.9A when measured

Comment: @PedroCosta 1.8A is a sane maximum current limit for most USB connectors. You can support 1.5A easily for BC protocols, but can't find many connectors rated for more than 1.8A. Most likely the monitor has active overcurrent protection IC instead of fuse. And you can't detect with multimeter if the supply is turned on and off due to overcurrent tens of times per second, because multimeter is a slow device giving you an average

Comment: @Justme That makes sense to me, i bought a pack of 100 LEDs so im safe to test them, let me see if i can find some 3V and 5V power supplies (instead of USB ports) to make some sanity checks on this, will report shortly

Comment: @Justme 5V burnout (which goes with the datasheet) and 3V Nominal at 150mA, makes sense, also measured the voltage of the powersupplies to make sure that they were giving the said voltage

Comment: @PedroCosta Do not connect LEDs directly to constat voltage power supplies. You need a constant current LED driver or at least a resistor to limit current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't safe. Do not use an USB port as a power supply.

The USB port tries to output 5V but your LEDs clamped the voltage down to 3.2V like you described because the current is not limited in any way.

There might be protection in the form of current limiting or some polyfuse, but it could have damaged the USB port. Good thing is you did not plug it into your expensive PC. Although the LED may now also be damaged.

And then there are standards that your device is violating.
An USB device must not draw more than 100mA current before negotiating how much current it needs and knowing if the requested amount is available.

So even if you do use a resistor, it is wrong to pull more than 100mA without asking for more than 100mA.

Imagine an USB port which can provide 500mA, and has a 4-port unpowered hub connected. The hub itself allocates 100mA, and maybe 3 ports take 100mA each, so only 100mA is available. If you plug in a 350mA LED, something either kicks in to protect from overcurrent, or blows a fuse permanently, or burns up a PCB track.

Comment: Something to note is that the USB ports in my monitor work even if the computer is off (even charging my phone pretty fast), which would led me to believe that the Vcc and Vss of the monitor's usb ports are tied to the monitor's power supply no?
For reference my monitor is an AOC 24g2u
Tho fortunatelly i did not connect it directly to the

Comment: @PedroCosta Yes, that is obvious, powered USB hubs exist, some of them providing supply for charging devices, supporting various battery charging standards, both open and proprietary standards.